# Upgrading to Ionic 2.2.0 and now getting errors about OpaqueToken and ModuleWithProviders

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have upgraded from Ionic 2.0.0-rc3 to 2.2.0. To do this I followed the instructions on their change log at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md and updated my package.json

If I now run ionic serve then I am seeing errors during the transpile stage. I am at a loss as I don't know anything about OpaqueToken or ModuleWithProviders and my searching around hasn't revealed anything.

```
MacBook-Pro-3:project chris$ ionic serve

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:serve /Users/chris/Documents/ionic/project
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8102" "--livereload-port" "35731"

[16:25:37]  ionic-app-scripts 1.1.4 
[16:25:37]  watch started ... 
[16:25:37]  build dev started ... 
[16:25:37]  clean started ... 
[16:25:37]  clean finished in 1 ms 
[16:25:37]  copy started ... 
[16:25:37]  transpile started ... 
[16:25:40]  typescript: Users/chris/node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/dist/es5/index.d.ts, line: 39 
            Cannot find name 'OpaqueToken'. 

[16:25:40]  typescript: Users/chris/node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/dist/es5/index.d.ts, line: 50 
      L39:  export declare const CloudSettingsToken: OpaqueToken;
      L40:  export declare function provideContainer(settings: CloudSettings): DIContainer;

            Cannot find name 'ModuleWithProviders'. 

      L49:  export declare class CloudModule {
      L50:      static forRoot(settings: CloudSettings): ModuleWithProviders;

[16:25:40]  transpile failed 
[16:25:40]  dev server running: http://localhost:8102/ 

[16:25:40]  watch ready in 2.83 s 
[16:25:40]  copy finished in 2.82 s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by doing the following

```
npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save

ionic platform remove ios

remove the node_modules directory

npm install
```

Voila!